# How to create a Hashicorp Vault user using Terraform

Tags: authentication, terraform, command-line-interface, hashicorp-vault, vault

I am trying to create a Vault user in Terraform but can't seem to find the appropriate command to do so. I've searched the Terraform Registry and also performed some online searches but all to no avail.

All I'm looking to do is create a user, using the corresponding Terraform command to the Vault CLI command below:

```
vault write auth/userpass/users/bob password="passworld123" policies="default"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are correct that you cannot currently manage anything in the `userpass` authentication engine beyond enablement with the Terraform provider for Vault. I would recommend a different authentication engine if you want to use TF to manage this. I would likewise recommend a different management tool if you want to use the `userpass` authentication engine (such as a software provisioner and not an infrastructure provisioner).

Answer (score 1):

@hitman126 I guess you can take use of 'vault' provider module and 'vault_auth_backend' resource block. I guess your code should look like something similar to below

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    vault = {
      source = "hashicorp/vault"
      version = "3.5.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "vault" {

}

resource "vault_auth_backend" "example" {
  type = "userpass"
}

resource "vault_generic_secret" "developer_sample_data" {
  path = "secret/foo"

  data_json = <<EOT
{
  "username": "bob",
  "password": "passworld123"
}
EOT
}
```

In above code block, path is one full logic path where we write given data.To write data into the "generic" secret backend mounted in Vault by default, this should be prefixed with 'secret/'.

This might not be a full-fledged solution, but you can try something like this

Solution-2 :

If you have installed vault in machine and you would like to achieve above use case using vault command alone(if you don't want to use terraform-vault provider), then you can try something below

1. create one small sh script with above vault command. (valut-write.sh)

```
touch vault-write.sh
```

let content of script can be similar to below

```
#!/bin/sh
vault write auth/userpass/users/bob password="passworld123" policies="default"
```

```
chmod +x vault-write.sh
```

2. Create a .tf file with null resource, local-exec provisioner and invoke this sh script.

```
touch vault.tf
```

contents of vault.tf file can be similar to below

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.1.1"
}

resource "null_resource" "vault_write" {

 provisioner "local-exec" {

    command = "/bin/sh vault-write.sh"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vault provides a `vault_generic_endpoint` resource that can be used for this purpose.

For example:

```
resource "vault_auth_backend" "userpass" {
  type = "userpass"
}

resource "vault_generic_endpoint" "u1" {
  depends_on           = [vault_auth_backend.userpass]
  path                 = "auth/userpass/users/bob"
  ignore_absent_fields = true

  data_json = <<EOT
{
  "policies": ["default"],
  "password": "passworld123"
}
EOT
}
```

It is important to remember that all data provided in the resource configuration will be written in cleartext to state and plan files generated by Terraform and will appear in the console output when Terraform runs.

You can find more information in the provider docs [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vault/latest/docs/resources/generic_endpoint)

You can find a longer tutorial that uses this approach [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/operations/codify-mgmt-oss)